# Why does the following code require initialization by a pointer?

Tags: pointers, constants

When I initialized the following array without pointer, I received the following error message:

> error: excess elements in char array initializer

Why do I need to initialize this array with a pointer?

```
const char MONTH_NAME[] ={"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 const char* MONTH_NAME[] ={"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

const char* GetOldMonthName(int month){
    if(1 <= month && month <= 12){
        return MONTH_NAME[month - 1];
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int month;

    cout << "Enter the month number." <<endl;
    cin  >> month;
    const char* name = GetOldMonthName(month);

    if(name == 0){
        cout << "That is not month." <<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout <<"The number is " << name << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this "non-pointer" form:

```
const char MONTH_NAME[] ={"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

`MONTH_NAME` is being declared as an **array of `const char`**. An array of `const char` (when terminated by a `'\0'`) is also known as a C-style string. But you are trying to initialize this string with an "array of  arrays of `const char`" (i.e. an array of strings). Hence, an error.

For example, the first element of your initialization array is `"Jan"`, which itself is an array of `const char` (a string).

In the alternative "pointer" form:

```
const char* MONTH_NAME[] ={"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

`MONTH_NAME` is being declared as an **array of pointers to `const char`**, which is properly initialized by the list of const strings in your code. Hence, no error.